# How to rank rows based upon the value in a column using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Edit:**

I altered the selected solution to this code and it achieved the intended result.

```
DENSE_RANK() 
    OVER (ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN f.empl_ssn = f.cov_ind_ssn
        THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, f.cov_ind_ssn ) AS [depend_no]
```

---

How would I go about assigning a rank value to the rows depending on the value in another column? I've read into using the RANK(), ROW_NUMBER(), and DENSE_RANK() functions and while I can rig the DENSE_RANK() to work in certain situations, when I expand my testing from just 1 family to all 172,000 rows of data, that solution falls through.

What I need to accomplish looks like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+------+---------------+-----------+
|  empl_ssn   | cov_ind_ssn | f_name | l_name | code | date_of_birth | depend_no |
+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+------+---------------+-----------+
| 000-11-0010 | 000-11-0011 | Joe    | Bob    |    1 | 12/25/72      |         2 |
| 000-11-0010 | 000-11-0010 | Morgan | Bob    |   18 | 9/14/71       |         1 |
| 000-11-0010 | 000-12-0102 | Little | Bob    |   19 | 2/16/06       |         3 |
| 000-11-0010 | 000-51-9212 | Wittle | Bob    |   19 | 8/12/04       |         4 |
| 000-11-0010 | 000-53-0013 | Tiny   | Bob    |   19 | 8/25/02       |         5 |
+-------------+-------------+--------+--------+------+---------------+-----------+
```

This data can and will be in any order, I've already used a few CTE's to take the data from 12 rows per person down to 1 row per person, I just need to assign them a depend_no now.

In the case that the empl_ssn and the cov_ind_ssn are equal, the depend_no should be 1 as this means they are the employee of the company. Anything after that should start from 2 and increment until all rows have been assigned a value.

---

Now, I've achieved this by using this CTE:

```
random AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    empl_ssn,
    cov_ind_ssn,
    relationship_code,
    DENSE_RANK()
    OVER (
      ORDER BY f.birthdate ) AS [depend_no]
  FROM full_data AS f
  WHERE empl_ssn = @current_employee
)
```

But that is obviously not viable because I cannot guarantee that the employee will always have been born first.

Just for references sake, I will post the entire block of code that I've written so far with anything sensitive striped out.

```
DECLARE @current_employee VARCHAR(11);
SET @current_employee = 'XXX-XX-XXXX';

WITH premiums AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          empl_ssn,
          premium_amount,
          month_covered
        FROM full_data
        WHERE empl_ssn = @current_employee
      ) AS src
      PIVOT (
        MAX(premium_amount)
      FOR month_covered
      IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) ) AS piv1
),
    offer_codes AS
  (
      SELECT *
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            empl_ssn,
            offer_code,
            month_covered
          FROM full_data
          WHERE empl_ssn = @current_employee
        ) AS src
        PIVOT (
          MAX(offer_code)
        FOR month_covered
        IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) ) AS piv1
  ),
    safe_harbor_codes AS
  (
      SELECT *
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            empl_ssn,
            safe_harbor_code,
            month_covered
          FROM full_data
          WHERE empl_ssn = @current_employee
        ) AS src
        PIVOT (
          MAX(safe_harbor_code)
        FOR month_covered
        IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]) ) AS piv1
  ),
    random AS
  (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        empl_ssn,
        cov_ind_ssn,
        relationship_code,
        DENSE_RANK()
        OVER (
          ORDER BY f.birthdate ) AS [depend_no]
      FROM full_data AS f
      WHERE empl_ssn = @current_employee
  )

SELECT DISTINCT
  f.empl_ssn,
  f.cov_ind_ssn,
  f.f_name,
  f.l_name,
  f.relationship_code,
  f.birthdate,

  r.depend_no,

  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[1] END    AS [emp_share_jan],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[2] END    AS [emp_share_feb],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[3] END    AS [emp_share_mar],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[4] END    AS [emp_share_apr],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[5] END    AS [emp_share_may],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[6] END    AS [emp_share_jun],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[7] END    AS [emp_share_jul],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[8] END    AS [emp_share_aug],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[9] END    AS [emp_share_sep],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[10] END   AS [emp_share_oct],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[11] END   AS [emp_share_nov],
  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    p.[12] END   AS [emp_share_dec],

  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[1] END    AS [offer_code_jan],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[2] END    AS [offer_code_feb],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[3] END    AS [offer_code_mar],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[4] END    AS [offer_code_apr],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[5] END    AS [offer_code_may],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[6] END    AS [offer_code_jun],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[7] END    AS [offer_code_jul],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[8] END    AS [offer_code_aug],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[9] END    AS [offer_code_sep],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[10] END   AS [offer_code_oct],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[11] END   AS [offer_code_nov],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] = o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    o.[12] END   AS [offer_code_dec],

  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[1] END    AS [safe_harbor_jan],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[2] END    AS [safe_harbor_feb],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[3] END    AS [safe_harbor_mar],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[4] END    AS [safe_harbor_apr],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[5] END    AS [safe_harbor_may],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[6] END    AS [safe_harbor_jun],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[7] END    AS [safe_harbor_jul],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[8] END    AS [safe_harbor_aug],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[9] END    AS [safe_harbor_sep],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[10] END   AS [safe_harbor_oct],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[11] END   AS [safe_harbor_nov],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] = S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    S.[12] END   AS [safe_harbor_dec],

  CASE WHEN p.[1] = p.[12]
    THEN p.[1]
  ELSE NULL END  AS [premium_all],
  CASE WHEN o.[1] <> o.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE o.[1] END AS [offer_all],
  CASE WHEN S.[1] <> S.[12]
    THEN NULL
  ELSE S.[1] END AS [harbor_all]
FROM
  premiums AS p
  JOIN offer_codes AS o ON p.empl_ssn = o.empl_ssn
  JOIN safe_harbor_codes AS S ON p.empl_ssn = S.empl_ssn
  JOIN full_data AS f ON p.empl_ssn = f.empl_ssn
  JOIN random AS r ON p.empl_ssn = r.empl_ssn
ORDER BY depend_no;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this (it seems like you're looking for an ordering rather than a ranking (other than the fact that the employee needs to be at the top of the list)?):

```
SELECT
    empl_ssn
    , cov_ind_ssn
    , relationship_code
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN empl_ssn = cov_ind_ssn THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, birthdate) depend_no
FROM full_data
WHERE empl_ssn = @current_employee
```

Comment: I tested both solutions and after making some slight modifications, this answer got me to the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case expression` in the ranking approach, e.g.

```
  SELECT
        empl_ssn
      , cov_ind_ssn
      , relationship_code
      , CASE WHEN empl_ssn = cov_ind_ssn  THEN 1 ELSE
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.birthdate) + 1
        END AS [depend_no]
  FROM full_data AS f
  WHERE empl_ssn = @current_employee
```